# Unable to add HDF file in QGIS on Mac OS

Tags: qgis, raster, hdf

I am using QGIS 3.28.1 Firenze version on Mac. After adding a hdf file, the following pop-ups are displayed: Unsupported Data Source or Invalid data source. The LULC data sets are retrieved from the USGS website. How to fix it?

Comment: Qgis doesn't support hdf files natively. A hdf is not like a grid raster like a geotiff. Do you have a link to the dataset you used?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The dataset works in Windows but on mac. I am attaching the zipped data via a drive link below, please have a look. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R_TVywKaYK6KJAZwKsO3oDkDdGrkFynA?usp=share_link